# How to configure .NET test assembly to use website web.config?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, testing

I've run into a problem setting up Selenium tests for an ASP.NET MVC project in cases where I need the settings provided in the web.config of the site under test. The problem is that I want to create a dummy user before running the test and this causes an error saying that the password-answer supplied is invalid. This is due to the test assembly not using the web.config, instead using default values for membership configuration.

I've tried to copy the relevant section (membership configuration) into the app.config of the assembly without luck, but I admit I'm just grasping at straws here.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, hope I got this right that you might want to access and manipulate web.config programmatically:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure. I just want the ASP.NET membership system to not use the default values when in a class library (from the test code).